# How to solve a SQL syntax error if it's generated by hibernate when trying to save an object in database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to save an object using session.save() method from hibernate. Everything worked well so far for other classes but now I'm stuck with this SQL syntax error and nothing that I found could help so far. Here is the console result:

```
Error update: could not execute statement
May 23, 2019 5:47:26 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option (is_answer, question_id, option_text) values (0, 97, 'asdfaoins')' at line 1
```

Here is the method from my QuestionDAO class:

```
@Transactional
    public void addQuestionOption(String text, int questionId, boolean isAnswer) {

    QuestionOption newOption = new QuestionOption();

    newOption.setText(text);
    newOption.setQuestionId(questionId);
    newOption.setIsAnswer(isAnswer);

    Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(QuestionOption.class);

    SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    try {

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(newOption);

        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error update: " + e.getMessage());
        session.getTransaction().rollback(); // get
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Here is my QuestionOption model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "option")
public class QuestionOption {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "option_text")
private String text;

@Column(name = "question_id")
private int questionId;

@Column(name = "is_answer")
private boolean isCorrectAnswer;



public QuestionOption(int id, String text, int questionId, boolean isAnswer) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.questionId = questionId;
    this.isCorrectAnswer = isAnswer;
}

public QuestionOption() {}

//getters & setters
```

And the call that I'm having is as simple as this:

```
 QuestionOptionDAO odao = new QuestionOptionDAO();
     odao.addQuestionOption("asdfaoins", 97, false);
```

I mention that I can insert in workbench without any problem if I just hardcode some entries. I tried the `saveOrUpdate()` method as well. Also, I'm using the exact same method for other classes and the insert work perfectly. Any idea why I get this error in this case?

Comment: Could you please add your table structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `option` is a reserved word in MySQL...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-O

Try calling your table something else or try what is suggested here...

https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-escape-table-column-names/

e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table("\"Option\"")
public class QuestionOption {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to log the SQL statement Hibernate sends to the DB.

This is described [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-log-sql-statements-and-their-parameters/).

It would be easier to find the problem when you paste it in a SQL client ([like HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/)). Or post the whole query here so we can have a look at it.